# Why do I keep getting Error 1172 in this MySQL trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

What I'm trying to do is this:

Create a trigger named trg_cust_balance that will automatically update the AC_CUSTOMER table’s CUS_BALANCE before a new CHARTER row is added. Use the CHARTER table’s CHAR_TOT_CHG as the update source (Assume that all charter charges are charged to the customer balance.)  In addition to the CHAR_TOT_CHG, add $25 for every quart of oil used on the charter.

This is my code:

```
create trigger trg_cust_balance
before insert on CHARTER
for each row
begin
declare CHG_PRIOR double;
declare OIL_QUANT double;

select CHAR_OIL_QTS into OIL_QUANT
from CHARTER
order by CUS_CODE;

select CHAR_TOT_CHG into CHG_PRIOR
from CHARTER
order by CUS_CODE;

update AC_CUSTOMER
set CUS_BALANCE = CUS_BALANCE + CHG_PRIOR + (OIL_QUANT * 25);
end;
// delimiter ;
```

So basically what I'm doing here is pulling the quantity of quarts of oil (CHAR_OIL_QTS) and the total charge (CHAR_TOT_CHG) and turning them into variables. Then trying to make the customer balance (CUS_BALANCE) equal to whatever it was plus said charges. However, I keep getting the 1172 error and I don't know why. I suspect it's got to do with the two select statements. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you can reduce it to following

But the update clause needs an other WHERE Clause so that the correct custimer gets the balanced changed

```
drop trigger if exists trg_cust_balance;
delimiter //
create trigger trg_cust_balance
before insert on CHARTER
for each row
begin

update AC_CUSTOMER
set CUS_BALANCE = CUS_BALANCE + NEW.CHAR_TOT_CHG + (NEW.CHAR_OIL_QTS * 25)
where AC_CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE = NEW.CUS_CODE;
end// 
delimiter ;

INSERT INTO CHARTER VALUES(10019,'2020-02-10','4278Y','TYS',644,3.8,4.5,167.4,0,10017);
```

Thsi runs with out a proem seee https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/29eiHwfNHDrL34VQ8CSPAF/1

Comment: Yeah I tried using it an after insert trigger and it's a no-brainer, but the problem instruction says to use a before insert trigger, so I imagine I'd lose points if I did it that way

Comment: you don't need the AFTER INSERT reallly but you need a WHERE CLAUSE that identifies the correct row.

Comment: I just tried creating a where statement that relates the customer id from the CHARTER and AC_CUSTOMER tables, but no luck, still getting that same error :/

Comment: please make a https://www.db-fiddle.com so that i can take a look at the code including the insert what produces the error

Comment: Sure. I will need to include everything right? Including the statements to create the tables and insert the values?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/29eiHwfNHDrL34VQ8CSPAF/0

Let me know if I messed up somewhere of if you need anything else

Comment: Ok you didn't copy my code completely see my updated answer

Comment: So looks like the only thing missing was the new. prefix for the regular variables instead of creating new variables?